# Microsoft Word preformatted shapes

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS word, I insert a shape (mostly arrows ), I change it's colour to Red and it's weight.

Repeat the above every time I need the same arrow,

Is there a way to 
1.Have an inventory of my custom shapes or
2.Set the defaults for e.g. the Arrow ?

Or any other way of not having to resort to copy paste a shape and trying to drag it around.

Comment: What version of MS Word are you using?

Comment: @music2myear 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2013 you can save a modified shape as AutoText (Building Block):

1. Select the shape in the document
2. **Insert** tab > **Text** > **Quick Parts** > **AutoText** > **Save Selection to AutoText Gallery**
3. Type the name for the shape and click OK.

*From here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1583429d-92b6-44ea-a3ce-36f76e9ce26d/how-to-save-a-customized-shape-reuse-it-later-in-the-word-2013-frequently?forum=officeitpro*